# FPDF second page does not match first

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm attempting to output a bunch of QRCodes using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) so that they may be saved and printed out. The print format I'm duplicating is the Avery 6572 Template.

**My problem** is that the first page of output is absolutely pristine, but then subsequent pages are completely mangled in regards to the Y position and each QR Code is on its own page.

I've honestly spent a couple days messing with Y positions, attempting to output my data through a table, attempting output with the MultiCell() method, all to no avail... the closest I was able to get is the following: http://www.galatium.net/qrcodes.pdf

Can someone kindly shed some light on what I'm missing?

Below is my code if you wish to duplicate it (note that you'll need your own image)

```
require_once('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

//$intids = explode(",", $_POST['intids']);

//Add 15 manually for the purpose of testing
$intids = array(
            -62016037,21924259,-768047323,1429473130,164704222,
            1815464709,-1787257749,621338038,-1511797412,-2134836004,
            2128460384,-180522171,-790468982,1589074358,-1227881486
        );

//Add 4 more to show brokenness
$intids[] = -62016037; //16
$intids[] = 21924259; //17
$intids[] = -768047323; //18
$intids[] = 1429473130; //19


//Verify there are intids, and that the first one is not empty
if (count($intids) > 0 && !empty($intids[0])) {
    $topMargin = 12; //Set document top margin to match Avery 6572 Template
    $labelWidth = 70; //Approx. width in mm of the label
    $labelHeight = 54; //Approx. height in mm of the label

    $pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetMargins(0, $topMargin, 0);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0); //Set bottom margin to 0

    $counter = 0;
    $col = 0;
    $row = 0;
    $y = $topMargin;

foreach ($intids as $intid) {
    if (is_numeric($intid)) {
        ++$counter;

        $pdf->SetY($y);
        //Adding 4 to replicate paper Avery Template margins
        if ($col) $pdf->SetX($pdf->GetX() + 4 + ($labelWidth * $col));

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 14);
        $pdf->Cell($labelWidth, 5, "Some Title for QRCode #".$counter."", 0, 1, 'C');

        if ($col) $pdf->SetX($pdf->GetX() + 4 + ($labelWidth * $col));

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 13);
        $pdf->Cell($labelWidth, 5, "Brief Content for #".$counter, 0, 1, 'C');

        if ($col) $pdf->SetX($pdf->GetX() + 4 + ($labelWidth * $col));

        //Image size: 135x135px Added 17mm to X for centering
        $pdf->Image('images/qrcodes/' . $intid . '.png', $pdf->GetX() + 17, $pdf->GetY());

        $pdf->SetY($pdf->GetY() + 36);
        if ($col) $pdf->SetX($pdf->GetX() + 4 + ($labelWidth * $col));

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        $pdf->Cell($labelWidth, 5, "Small Text for #".$counter, 0, 0, 'C');

        //If the third column, reset column count and set Y to start at next line
        if (++$col == 3) {
            $y = ($labelHeight * ++$row) + $topMargin;
            $col = 0;
        }
    }
}


$pdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce the issue, but I suspect the auto page break is not behaving as you wish. My suggestion is to turn off auto page break and instead add a page with AddPage() when you detect the last row is complete.

Comment: @bmb All that did was add a single white page. QRCodes #16-19 don't show anywhere. I set `$pdf->AutoPageBreak(false, 0)` and added `if ($row > 0 && $row % 5 == 0) $pdf->AddPage();` after the `if (++$col == 3) {` line.

Comment: @bmb Thanks! You steered me in the right direction. It was a matter of doing the above, and then resetting the Y/row again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bmb who led me down the Auto Page Break path.

For future visitors and to those who are curious, the solution is as follows:

Set `$pdf->AutoPageBreak(false, 0);`

Then change these lines:

```
if (++$col == 3) {
    $y = ($labelHeight * ++$row) + $topMargin;
    $col = 0;
}
```

To:

```
if (++$col == 3) {
    $y = ($labelHeight * ++$row) + $topMargin;

    if ($row > 0 && $row % 5 == 0) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $y = $topMargin;
        $row = 0;
    }

    $col = 0;
}
```